# Filling a moving cone shape is not working,

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the Flash API to draw a moving cone shape that will later work as a laser beam.  However I cannot fill it even though the shape has no gaps.

Here's the current result I get and I draw in the following order as shown by the numerals.

[Link to current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34pBM.jpg)

Before all this I start a beginFill(...) and end it all, after all lines have been drawn, with an endFill().

As mentioned the cone moves as is to be used as an effect later (Between each point I will fade the line style).  So what I do is to store the points for each OnEnterFrame event and draw the lines (1 & 2) based on these points.  The laser beams has a direction.

If it remains static and I draw it this following way it works (On the OnEnterFrame event):

```
                    graphics.clear();
        graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000);
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);

        var dx:Number = end.x - source.x;
        var dy:Number = end.y - source.y;

        var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

        var endX1:Number = end.x + 20 * Math.cos(angle - 90);
        var endY1:Number = end.y + 20 * Math.sin(angle - 90);
        var endX2:Number = end.x + 20 * Math.cos(angle + 90);
        var endY2:Number = end.y + 20 * Math.sin(angle + 90);


        graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF);
        graphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
        graphics.lineTo(endX1, endY1);

        graphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
        graphics.lineTo(endX2, endY2);
        graphics.lineTo(endX1, endY1);
        graphics.endFill();
```

That being said this way I dont draw number 4 line (As displayed on the picture).

I'm running out of ideas, the shape is clearly closed but the fill won't work.  Here's my full code for the OnEnterFrame event for the "moving" cone effect.  Here

```
public function update():void
    {
        /*
        graphics.clear();
        //graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000);
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        //graphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
        //graphics.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
        */
        var dx:Number = end.x - source.x;
        var dy:Number = end.y - source.y;

        var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

        var endX1:Number = end.x + 20 * Math.cos(angle - 90);
        var endY1:Number = end.y + 20 * Math.sin(angle - 90);
        var endX2:Number = end.x + 20 * Math.cos(angle + 90);
        var endY2:Number = end.y + 20 * Math.sin(angle + 90);

        /*
        graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF);
        graphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
        graphics.lineTo(endX1, endY1);

        graphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
        graphics.lineTo(endX2, endY2);
        graphics.lineTo(endX1, endY1);
        graphics.endFill();

        return;
        */

        var x:Number  = currentPoint.x;
        var y:Number  = currentPoint.y;
        var x2:Number = currentPoint2.x;
        var y2:Number = currentPoint2.y;

        points[0].x = x;
        points[0].y = y;

        points2[0].x = x2;
        points2[0].y = y2;


        //::  Interpolate Current Point
        currentPoint    = Point.interpolate(new Point(endX1, endY1), source, progress);
        currentPoint2   = Point.interpolate(new Point(endX2, endY2), source, progress);


        //::  Add new point with properties
        if (progress < 1.0 )
        {
             points.splice(1, 0, {x: x, y: y, life: getTimer(), thickness: 2 + (20 * progress)});
             points2.splice(1, 0, {x: x2, y: y2, life: getTimer(), thickness: 2 + (20 * progress)});
        }

        //::  Line 1
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF, 1);
        graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);

        graphics.moveTo(x, y);

        for (var i:int = 1; i < points.length; i++) 
        {
            //::  Point dead, remove it
            if (getTimer() - points[i].life > lifetime)
            {
                points.splice(i--, 1);
            }
            //::  Update point life and draw graphics
            else 
            {
                var currentLife:Number  = (getTimer() - points[i].life);
                var perc:Number         = Math.abs(1 - (currentLife / lifetime));

                //graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF, perc);

                //::  Prev point
                var px:Number = points[i - 1].x;
                var py:Number = points[i - 1].y;

                graphics.lineTo(px, py);                                    
            }
        }


        //::  Line 2
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        graphics.moveTo(x2, y2);

        for (var i:int = 1; i < points2.length; i++) 
        {
            //::  Point dead, remove it
            if (getTimer() - points2[i].life > lifetime)
            {
                points2.splice(i--, 1);
            }
            //::  Update point life and draw graphics
            else 
            {
                var currentLife:Number  = (getTimer() - points2[i].life);
                var perc:Number         = Math.abs(1 - (currentLife / lifetime));

                //graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF, perc);

                //::  Prev point
                var px:Number = points2[i - 1].x;
                var py:Number = points2[i - 1].y;

                graphics.lineTo(px, py);                                    
            }
        }



        //::  Close 3 & 4
        if (points.length > 1)
        {
            graphics.moveTo(points[points.length-2].x, points[points.length-2].y);
            graphics.lineTo(points2[points2.length-2].x, points2[points2.length-2].y);
        }

        graphics.moveTo(x, y);
        graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
        graphics.endFill();



        //::  Progress
        progress += progressSpeed;      
        if (progress >= 1.0)    progress = 1.0;
```

The code is pretty safe explanatory.  If you need more info I will provide!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem occurs because you are moving the drawing position twice, and that is confusing Flash about what should be filled.

Typically, when I draw a shape like this, I do only 1 call to `moveTo()` at the beginning, and then draw each line from the current end point. That "current end point" changes as you draw each line. I suggest you modify the code so it does the drawing something like this:

```
moveTo(startX, startY);
lineTo(endX1, endY1);
lineTo(endX2, endY2);
lineTo(endX3, endY3);
lineTo(startX, startY);
```

I believe what is happening is that when you make that 2nd call to `moveTo()` Flash tries to  fill whatever has been previously drawn. But since you've only drawn 2 lines, there's nothing to fill.  It resets it's state (about what should be filled), and then you draw another line or two. When you call `endFill()`, it only looks at what has been drawn since the last `moveTo()` and again decides there is nothing to fill.

Comment: Well that certainly did the trick Sunil D.!  Thanks for the answer!  Would give you rep if I could!